# I was trying to understand why $0<\frac{x}{1-x}<\infty$ became $0<x<1$.

Tags: inequality

I was trying to understand why $0<\frac{x}{1-x}<\infty$, became $0<x<1$.

I was thinking of multiplying the inequalities to $1-x$, but $(1-x)\infty$ won't yield to $1$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$

If $x = 1$, the function is not well defined.

If $x > 1$, $x>0$ but $1-x<0$, hence $f(x) <0$.

If $x \leq 0$, $x \leq 0$, and $1-x > 0$, hence $f(x) \leq 0$.

Hence the only possibility left for $f(x) >0$ would be $0<x<1.$

Alternatively, first note that $x \neq 1$. After which for $0< \frac{x}{1-x}$, we multiply both sides by $(1-x)^2$.

Hence $$0<x(1-x)$$

Solving the inequality gives us $0<x<1.$

Be careful that we can't just multiply $1-x$ directly without first checking if you might have multiplied with a negative number.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, because I didn't understand why my teacher need to get the reciprocal of x/1-x first before arriving to 0 < X < 1

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the $< \infty$ redundant. You're looking for where the function $\frac{x}{1 - x}$ is positive. I would solve it by noticing that you have a quotient of two quantities $x$ and $1 - x$. In order to be positive, we need both of them to be positive or both to be negative.

We have $x > 0$ and $1 - x > 0$, if and only if $0 < x < 1$. On the other hand, $x < 0$ and $1 - x < 0$ if and only if $x < 0$ and $x > 1$, which is impossible. Thus, the solution is $0 < x < 1$.